# Why does creating an S3 directory create an invisible file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My problem:

1. I log into the AWS console. I create a bucket, `myBucket`, and a new directory `myDirectory`. In `myBucket/myDirectory` I upload a file, `myData.txt`.
2. I write some code to iterate over the contents of `myBucket/myDirectory`. E.g.

```py
for item in myBucket.objects.filter(Prefix='myDirectory/'):
    print(item)
```

This prints:

> myDirectory/
>
> myDirectory/myData.txt

**What's `myDirectory/`?!**

Debugging:

1. In the AWS S3 console, `myData.txt` is the only thing in its directory
2. In the AWS CLI, I type: `aws s3 ls myBucket/myFolder/` and it prints:

> 2019-09-09 23:33:14 0
>
> 2019-09-09 23:33:36 11 data.txt

If I run

```
aws s3 rm myBucket/myDirectory/
```

The mysterious object goes away, **but in the AWS console my directory is still there, with my file inside of it**. Now my printing logic works as expected. Neither my code nor the CLI sees the empty file (`myDirectory/`) any more.

Questions:

1. Why does this happen? Is it a bug, or does it serve some purpose?
2. What's the right way of dealing with this, so my code can assume that when I list things under a prefix, I don't get ghost objects that exactly match that prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 is a flat object storage system. It does not support directories.

It does, however, support the concept of a **common prefix**, which is effectively the same thing.

The easiest way to handle it is **do not bother creating directories**. For example, if I create a new bucket and then run this command:

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/folder1/folder2/foo.txt
```

This will create an object with a Key of `folder1/folder2/foo.txt`.

In the Amazon S3 management console, `folder1` and `folder2` will be shown, but they don't actually exist.

Then, if I was to delete the object:

```
aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket/folder1/folder2/foo.txt
```

Not only would the object disappear, but the folders would disappear too, because they never existed.

If the bucket *does* have zero-length files that were created via the "Create Folder" button, you can filter them out in your code by ignoring any zero-length objects.

Answer (score 0):

S3 buckets don't have "directories". There are only objects.

By convention, objects often have slashes in their name to imply a hierarchy, and the S3 APIs have some support for condensing groups of objects with names that share a prefix. This *sort of* simulates directories -- but not entirely. There is no special significance to an object whose name ends in a slash; it's just an object with a funny name.

So. What you're doing here is creating two objects named `myDirectory/` and `myDirectory/myData.txt`. They are both objects, not directories; the first one did not need to exist for the second one to be created, and deleting the first one does not remove the second one.

Answer (score 0):

`mydirectory/` is a prefix that’s essentially an object. when listing that path, `mydirectory/` shows up as an object on the list in addition to the objects in it:

`s3://my-bucket s3://my-bucket/mydirectory/ s3://mybucket/mydirectory/mydata.txt`

if we delete mydirectory/ prefix, we’ll only be left with:

`s3://my-bucket s3://mybucket/mydirectory/mydata.txt`

the `mydata.txt` object will still have `mydirectory/` as part of its path, even though `mydirectory/` prefix doesn’t exist anymore. that said, if we delete `mydata.txt` object and then list the bucket afterwards, we’ll only be left with:
`s3://my-bucket`

so yeah, it’s possible to create `s3://mybucket/mydirectory/mydata.txt` straight up inside the bucket without first creating the prefix `mydirectory/`